# Placeholder plugin not working in the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-7, placeholder

I'm working in an application using visual studio and I tried to use some jquery plugins which add support of placeholder for ie<10 in the server but it's not working. When I use it locally it's good it works, but when I move the files to the server it doesn't work. Also I tried to copy the content of the js file to the page to make sure the problem is not coming from the path, and the same result. I tried with those plugins :

https://github.com/mkdynamic/jquery-placeholders

https://github.com/dciccale/placeholder-enhanced

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

**EDIT :**
This is the code:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//This is the function which creates the inputs in javascript
function createTextBox(evt, unknownBtn, nonOwner, subjNumber) {
    evt.preventDefault ? evt.preventDefault() : (evt.returnValue = false);
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById('<%=driverList.ClientID%>');
    var inputElement = document.createElement("input");
    inputElement.id = "comment" + appender;
    inputElement.type = "text";
    inputElement.className = "UndiscDrivers_UnknownTxt " + subjNumber;
    inputElement.setAttribute("maxlength", 150);
    inputElement.setAttribute("placeholder", "Type a reason for choosing this option");
    inputElement.setAttribute("onkeydown", "this.className = this.className.replace(' error', '');");
    if (nonOwner) {
        inputElement.style.left = "97px";
        inputElement.style.width = "60%";
    }
    else {
        inputElement.style.width = "60%";
    }
    //inputElement.setAttribute("style", "border:2px solid  #00FFFF; color:black;");

    var brElement = document.createElement("br");
    brElement.setAttribute("class", subjNumber);
    insertAfter(unknownBtn, brElement);

    //var BrAfterUnknownBtn = unknownBtn.nextElementSibling;

    insertAfter(brElement, inputElement);

    appender++;
}

 //This is the function which add the support for ie<10
 $(function() {
            // Invoke the plugin
            $('input, textarea').placeholder({customClass:'my-placeholder'});
            // That’s it, really.

            var html;

            if ($.fn.placeholder.input && $.fn.placeholder.textarea) {
                html = '<strong>Your current browser natively supports <code>placeholder</code> for <code>input</code> and <code>textarea</code> elements.</strong> The plugin won’t run in this case, since it’s not needed. If you want to test the plugin, use an older browser.';
            } else if ($.fn.placeholder.input) {
                html = '<strong>Your current browser natively supports <code>placeholder</code> for <code>input</code> elements, but not for <code>textarea</code> elements.</strong> The plugin will only do its thang on the <code>textarea</code>s.';
            }

            if (html) {
                $('<p class="note">' + html + '</p>').insertBefore('form');
            }
        });
```

in this case I'm using this plugin https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Thank you !

Comment: show your code please

Comment: I added the code. Thank you !

Comment: do you have an html file aswell?

Comment: The scripts are inside a user control (.ascx), called inside an Aspx page.